# Unity unresponsive after login; restarting Unity from tty works

Tags: 14.04, freeze, lts, tty

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on an older machine. 
After login, Unity becomes unresponsive. I can move the cursor, but no keyboard command or click seems to have any effect.

Moving to tty and executing

Unity

results in a working Unity GUI.

Any ideas how to get a working Unity after the intial login?

Best,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a couple of months ago and here is how i solved it, I hope it works for you too:

First try to reset unity:

```
unity --reset
```

If this fail then do the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Then I did the what is suggested by @SiddharthaRT [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/223634/476968):